# Can't POST data to PHP from jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm trying to post some data from a form into a controller with jQuery. 
But I'm having difficulties here.

I have a form with some inputs and a button calling my script.

The Button

```
  <button onclick="save('layoutstyle');">save</button>
```

And the script

```
function save(action) {

jQuery("#formTest").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = jQuery(this);

    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        // TO DO
        url:  '/template/templates/nwmadm/controller.php',
        data: 'save='+ action+'&data='+ serializedData,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {

            jQuery('#content').html(data);

        }
    });

})
```

}

And the controller in php looks like this

```
    if (isset($_POST["save"])) {
    switch ($_POST["save"]) {

        case "layoutstyle":
        $return = $_POST["data"];
        echo $return;
        break;

        case "surveys":
        echo "This is the Surveys site";
        break;

        default:
        echo "Return 404 page not found";

    }
}
```

But I'm only getting the first input through to the controller. And it is a string not an array.

What do I do? How do I get all the inputs from the form into my controller as an array?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: What if you change to `var serializedData = $form.serializeArray();
serializedData.push({ name: "submit", value: action });` and then `jQuery.ajax({ ... data: serializedData, ...});`? This way to add `submit` to your form serialized array, and send all through `serializedData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `JQuery.ajax()` you are using code:

```
data: 'save='+ action+'&data='+ serializedData,
```

`serializedData` is a string, which looks like this `field1=val1&field2=val2`. It means, that resulting data string will look such that:

```
save=layoutstyle&data=field1=val1&field2=val2
```

And it seems malformed. Instead, try to use this code

```
data: 'save=' + action + '&' + serializedData
```

In your PHP controller you must be able to access parameters of a request:

```
$action = $_POST["save"];
$field1 = $_POST["field1"];
$field2 = $_POST["field2"];
```

Comment: but im only getting the first field thrugh to the controller "layoutstyle", The other fileds im not getting.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by this. Check out the whole request first (print to console). Does it contains fields you are looking for?

Comment: well, okay i actually don't know why. But now your code i working so this was the answer for me... thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't could try your code but, i think you need to set disabled mode for controls on callback function, after form submitting event

You need set this control inside your form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="action" />
```

This is an custom ajax handler example that i used in some projects. 
In your form tag, set onsubmit event with the handler:

onsubmit="javascript:ajaxHandlerForm(this, 'your_action' );"

```
/**
 * Custom ajax form handler. 
 * @param {object} obj Reference to form
 * @param {String} action Name of Action 
 * @returns {Void}
 */
function ajaxHandlerForm(obj, action){
    // Prevent submit
    event.preventDefault();
    // Set the action. #action is an input hidden in the form
    $( "#action" ).val(action);
    // Set jQuery Ajax post : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
    $.post($(obj).prop( "action" ), $(obj).serialize(),
        function(data){
            // Set disabled mode
            $(obj).find("input, select, button, textarea")
                    .prop("disabled", true);
            // 
            $( "#content" ).html(data);
    });
}
```